# OSX virtual machines for Visual Studio and Azure

Tags: windows, virtualization

I will be starting a new job in a couple of weeks, and I've been asked to spec out a machine I'd like to work on. As a UI Developer, I am much more comfortable developing in OSX.

The company I will be working for develops on .NET and deploys as an Azure cloud application. I know that I can run Windows as a virtual machine, but I need to make an informed decision about whether I will be able to smoothly run Visual Studio and run the Azure cloud application.

Any thoughts? Performance issues? Workflow headaches?

Answer (score 3):

I program a lot in Visual Studio. I use parallels and Windows 7 and a MacBook Pro. Works great. You'll want to max out the ram on your machine, other than that you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does that include compiling and actively running the application within the emulated Windows environment?

Comment: From my experience with other developers who do exactly the same thing, yes. As stated by svaha RAM is crucial. An SSD based host would also be recommended to reduce disk wait times.

Comment: Yes. Compiling, runnning are not a problem. I haven't worked with Azure cloud applications, but I am developing asp.net mvc 3 websites. I really haven't run across any limitations, and with the 'Coherence' functionality it still 'feels' like a mac. You can seamlessly switch between Visual Studio and your finder, Photoshop, etc. I'm using a MacBook Pro (2.4Ghz Duo, 8GB Ram)...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the Windows VM on an external drive (preferably, Thunderbolt or FW800 based).  As others have said, make sure you max out the RAM of the Mac to be able to give Windows 4GB of RAM as well as the host the same amount or more.